# How do I get rid of this autogenerate ID by Firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

Here's the problem, how do I eliminate this id autogenerated by firebase?:

```
      var key_des = Object.keys(newItem)[1];
  var key_val = Object.keys(newItem)[2]

  var Income_data = {
    name: newItem[key_des],
    value: newItem[key_val]
  }
  var expense_data = {
    name: newItem[key_des],
    value: newItem[key_val]
  }
  console.log(Income_data)

  ref_income.push(Income_data, expense_data)
```

What's on firebase

[image: What's on firebase]